# How to Install GloMoSim 2.03 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and need to install [glomosim](http://pcl.cs.ucla.edu/projects/glomosim/) i am a newbie and i am experiencing problem.Does redhat platform based installation will work for ubuntu .Also if it does pleaseexplain how to do it.it will be very helpful.Thank you.also can you tell me how to set environment variables

Comment: http://ce.sharif.ir/courses/85-86/1/ce657/resources/root/Glomosim/GloMoSim%202.03%20Installation%20on%20Linux.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Install Parsec by typing

```
    sudo apt-get install parsec47
```

2) Download GloMoSim from http://pcl.cs.ucla.edu/projects/glomosim/obtaining_glomosim.html

3) Change into the glomosim-2.03/glomosim/main

```
    cd glomosim-2.03/glomosim/main
```

4) Build by typing:

```
    make
```

To the set the environment variables edit the .bashrc in your home directory and type for example:

```
    export PCC_DIRECTORY="/home/mydir"
```

and save the .bashrc file. Logout and login again then type the following at the command line to make sure the environment variable is set:

```
    echo $PCC_DIRECTORY
```

you should see /home/mydir